# What does the process 'Locum' do?

Tags: macos, mac, process

I am seeing a process titled, 'Locum' show up in my OS X process list. Does anyone know the details of what this process does?

Comment: If you see that is using a large amount of resources, you are probably emptying your trash or the trash is being emptied in the background; it can also eat CPU if you have a large number of "preview" windows opened.

Comment: Locum also appears when copying old Time Machine data sets from one drive to another.  The finder needs escalated privileges to be able to copy everything that's inside the backups.

Comment: @user117090 — What would the process Locum have to do with "preview" windows ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Google says that it's a helper process for Finder, that does all the stuff Finder would need escalated privileges for.

Comment: Yup, Locum is used for privilege escalation: http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=8293436

Comment: And you should always kill Locum whenever you kill Finder while doing anything privileged because it'll keep hogging resources for whatever Finder was doing.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what's said, if you choose to "**Secure Empty Trash...**" in Finder, Locum will consume a lot of resources because it will re-write the data (possibly several times) of where your trashed items resided. This will ensure you can never ever recover them.